# How to change application to library in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, monodevelop

I intended to build a C# library in Xamarin but selected application instead. When I try to build I get the `no main method` error. How do I change the build to build a library instead of an application?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer my question in 20 seconds of posting.

Under `Project -> [Project Name] Options -> Build -> General`.
Change executable to library.